# Python: extract smth from string with condition

Tags: python, regex

I have data, that looks like

```
Respublika Tatarstan, Kazan'
Krasnodar Krai, Krasnodar
Tverskaya region, Tver
```

Desired output:

```
respublika Tatarstan
Krasnodar krai
Tverskaya region
```

I tried to use

```
for addr in df.address.values.tolist():
    re.findall(r'(\w+( krai| region))|((?:respublika )\w+)', addr)
```

But it returns list of tuples and don't find object after `respublika`.

Comment: It just looks like you want everything until the first comma, so why not `line.split(',', 1)[0]`?

Comment: Or, if you're using pandas, `df.address.str.split(',', 1).str[0]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not all strings looks like this. Sometimes there are smth before this. So I need to use regex

Comment: Then you may add some other actual data.

Comment: @PetrPetrov Then please make it clear with more data and expected outputs, it is really unclear what you are asking at this point.

Comment: Пётр, *Sometimes there are smth before this. So I need to use regex* - we cannot help you if you do not come up with exact requirements for the pattern. You can use regex to extract substrings following some pattern in specific contexts - but you should let us - and yourself, too - know what the contexts are.

Comment: Try [`(?ui)\b[A-ZА-Я]\w*\s+(?:krai|region)|respublika\s+[A-ZА-Я]\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/EuqF8M/2), see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/nxIuAP). If it is what you need, I will post with explanations. I assume you might want to also support Cyrrilic uppercase letters, just guessing :)

Comment: See https://ideone.com/nxIuAP

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
import re
rx = r"\b[A-Z]\w*\s+(?:[kK]rai|[rR]egion)|\b[rR]espublika\s+[A-Z]\w*"
s = "Something in Respublika Tatarstan, Kazan\nWhat a Krasnodar Krai, Krasnodar I have seen!\nIn Tverskaya region, Tver, it is not so uncommon."
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

The idea is to match any capitalized word before `region`, `Region`, `krai` or `Krai`, or the capitalized word after `Respublika` or `respublika`.

Sede the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VO168n). If you want to only match letters, replace `\w` with `[^\W\d_]`.

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/EuqF8M/4).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]\w*` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with 0+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:[kK]rai|[rR]egion)` - `region`, `Region`, `krai` or `Krai`
- `|` - or
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[rR]espublika` - `Respublika` or `respublika`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]\w*` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with 0+ word chars